# Difference between $Bundle install and $Bundle update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

Could you tell me, whats the difference between:

```
$Bundle update
```

and

```
$Bundle install
```

Answer (score 94, accepted):

`bundle update` and `bundle install` can both install the gems you specified in Gemfile but missing in gems.

But `bundle update` does one thing more to upgrade:

1. If the gems specified in Gemfile don't have version, it will upgrade to whatever latest.
2. If the gems specified in Gemfile have version controlled with `~>`, it will upgrade to the latest **at the final digit**, the patch version.

   For example, if you have a gem in Gemfile

   ```
   'foo_gem', '~> 2.1.0'
   ```

   `bundle update` will check if newer version of 2.1.x is available in cloud. Say your current version is 2.1.2 and what's latest in cloud is 2.1.5, it will install 2.1.5. But if `2.2.6` is the newest, it won't do anything.

**Better practice in my opinion**

1. Always add version to critical gems like `rails`.
2. Stick to `bundle install`(or `bundle` which is default to `install`) in most cases. Only do `bundle update` when it's really necessary and you are fully prepared for the result.

Comment: So, as I good understood:
if I have 'foo_gem', '~> 2.1.0' , the main difference is:
bundle update - install version 2.1.* (latest), and
bundle install - install version 2.1.0

Comment: @shuffla90, in this case, `bundle install` will still install the latest gem say 2.1.5 if you don't have this gem. But, if you already have this gem at 2.1.1, `bundle install` will do nothing.

Comment: got it, muchos gracias, for your time :)

Comment: Just for more details have a look at http://ryanbigg.com/2011/01/why-you-should-run-bundle-update and http://robots.thoughtbot.com/rubys-pessimistic-operator

Comment: @BillyChan why is `adding version to critical gems` important? Can't we just let it update to the latest version?

Comment: @zack, the reason is the latest version might be better, but is not guaranteed to work nicely with your app. Some APIs might change, some might be deprecated, some results might be returned differently. You never know unless you studied the doc. It's always better to only upgrade when really needed, with intention.

Comment: @BillyChan i'm new to this but i've found that bundle update can push you back to an earlier version too if you specified an earlier version for a gem(useful in case of eg an incompatibility). So it's good for that too. That comment and more significantly, Your answer as it currently is, makes it look like it's for upgrading, going later only, but that's not the case as it can change a gem to an earlier version too.

Comment: Also include version numbers in your Gemfile. Unless you wanna fall into dependency hell. Which is where I'm at right now.

Answer (score 6):

`Bundle Update`s the gems specified (all gems, if none are specified), ignoring the previously installed gems specified in the Gemfile.lock. In general, you should use `bundle install` to install the same exact gems and versions across machines.

Comment: And bundle install could recommend doing bundle update. e.g.  bundle install could say, for a gem  `The bundle currently has blahgem locked at 5.11.1. Try running bundle update blahgem`,   (or just bundle update).