# how to pass the password in the script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shell, sh

I am writing a script where I am updating the ruby gems by `bundle update` command but it is asking the password with message **Enter your password to install the bundled RubyGems to your system:**

I have to pass the password silently without knowing user or in other ways i have to make it as automated.
currently I have do this with system command as `system 'bundle update'`

How can I do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the way you installed ruby, you need sudo privileges in order to run `bundle update`.

If you would like to run the bundle command without sudo privileges, you need to `chown` the gem folders.

You can do this by cd-ing into the path of your gems, and then `sudo chown -R username:groupname`

Comment: but why it didn't ask the password for `bundle install`

Comment: check out this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16495626/difference-between-bundle-install-and-bundle-update)
It may be that bundle install isn't doing anything because you haven't added any new gems, while with update it's looking for new versions