# RubyGems.org defaulting to old version of Gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

So I built a gem and pushed it to RubyGems with:

```
gem build MYGEM
```

and

```
gem push MYGEM
```

All is well. After making a few updates, I built the new Gem and incremented the version. After I pushed to RubyGems.org, the new gem version lived on RubyGems, but it is not the default version that is downloaded when someone runs "bundle install".

How can I change this to pull the correct version?

I know I can specify a specific version in the Gemfile, but I feel I should be able to pull down the latest version when bundling.

**Edit:**

Here's the gem for reference: [ten_thousand_feet](https://rubygems.org/gems/ten_thousand_feet)

Notice how there are more recent versions in the 'Versions' section but that it defaults to the first version.

Comment: They might have to run `bundle update` first to force pulling down the latest version of the gem. See this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16495626/difference-between-bundle-install-and-bundle-update) for the difference between `bundle install` and `bundle update`.

Comment: I ran bundle update and it still pulled down the older version. What's odd is that even when I go to rubygems.org and look at the gem, the default version that is shown is also the old one. When I go to list all versions, the newer version is listed, but it does not take precedence for some reason.

Comment: I think the issue is that v0.0.111 is sequentially after v0.0.38 since 111 > 38. I'm guessing that the version number takes precedence over the date released. I think you're going to have to yank v0.0.111 for things to work.

Comment: Awesome, yep this was the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check out semantic versioning: http://semver.org/

Your version number of 0.0.111 is higher/newer than 0.0.38.  Release dates have nothing to do with versioning numbers.

Comment: Great reference. I guess I assumed it would use 0.0.111 vs 0.0.380. I'll read up on this. Thanks.